# Nginx, wordpress: Unable to proper reverse proxy caching due to Set-Cookie. Recommendation for a good strategy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, wordpress, cache, http-proxy

I am trying to do reverse proxy caching for a wordpress blog and I am hit with snags.

The initial configuration was a simple reverse caching like this

```
  location / {
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme://$host$request_uri";
    proxy_cache staticfilecache;
    proxy_pass http://wordpressapache;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    proxy_cache_valid       200 302 10d;
```

I quickly realized that logged in users will be sent for a toss with and so I did

```
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

      location / {
        # If logged in, don't cache.
        if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author_|wordpress_(?!test_cookie)|wp-postpass_" ) {
          set $do_not_cache 1;
        }
        proxy_cache_key "$scheme://$host$request_uri $do_not_cache";
        proxy_cache staticfilecache;
        proxy_pass http://wordpressapache;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        proxy_cache_valid       200 302 10d;

  }
```

But this didn’t work since ***Nginx 1.0+ does not cache responses that has Set-Cookie***. To my surprise even all anonymous user hits result in `Set-Cookie`. An example below.

[image]

Now I can’t do a

```
proxy_ignore_headers  "Set-Cookie";
proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
```

since this will also not pass cookies for logged in users. I did something like this

```
      location ~* wp\-.*\.php|wp\-admin {
          proxy_pass http://wordpressapache;
      }
```

But then the logged in users will also come back to the blog page and their cookies will be rejected.

One other way is to do [something like this through plugin and send X-Accel-Expires.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-proxy-cache-integrator/)

```
function add_xaccel_header() {
    # Set the X-Accel-Expires header to never cache the page if it looks like the page needs to be tailored for a user.
    $user_cookie_there = false;
    foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value){
        if( preg_match('/wordpress_(?!test_cookie)|comment_author|wp-postpass/', $key) ){
            $user_cookie_there = true;
        }
    }
    if($user_cookie_there){
        header("X-Accel-Expires: 0");
    }
}

add_action('init','add_xaccel_header');
```

But then the hide cookie is creating issues. Removing hide cookie breaks the caching too.

What’s a **good strategy to cache pages for anonymous users using Nginx** that can be invalidated by logged-in users. Perhaps using `proxy_cache_bypass`?

Comment: Making '$do_not_cache' part of your proxy key, is not actually preventing caching there. You'll want to use the proxy_cache_bypass $do_not_cache instead.